# How to get mean directly from a csv row range in R?

Tags: r, csv, statistics, mean

[image]

Following is my code to read more than 1000 csv files, where each file has over 1000 rows and 4 columns. Each csv file has only 4 columns, such as ID, values, param1, param2. My current code snippet reads each file separately with their respective file names into a data frame. It's pretty clean frame per se. Because it's already implemented, I am only looking for a code that can be integrated to my function.

e.g. input

```
200 4.864 ne15 hx1
201 4.872 ne12 hx3
202 4.898 ne10 hx9
203 4.815 ne23 hx1
204 4.699 ne14 hx3
...
212 4.813 ne20 hx2
213 4.763 ne18 hx8
...
```

Output :
e.g.

```
index  row#.   value     filename
# mean should be the value for row 2 to 20
# it needs to be output in R under row 202
154    202.0   4.337     1wq.csv
164    225.0   4.358     1wq.csv
174    250.0   4.421     1wq.csv
184    275.0   4.498     1wq.csv
194    300.0   4.513     1wq.csv
```

Instead of getting 2 to 20 conseuctive values from csv file row (18 values) in that column, I want to get the mean value corresponding to values from row 2 to 20. How can I do that?

```
#set working directly to the folder where csv files are located
files <- list.files(pattern='.csv')
m = data.frame()
 for (k in 1:length(files)){
    csv = read.csv(files[k], header = FALSE)

    #picking up 2:20 consecutive values, value for row 50,120,150 so on
    data = csv[c(2:20, 50, 120, 150, 175, 200), c(1,2)]

    #-pivot transform col/row- data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
    #but that line screwed up the data
    #when those selected values are with NA/blanks
    data$file = files[k]

    m = rbind(m, data)
 }
```

With thanks to both the answers, I managed the following:
I will try AdamQuek's answer separately again to improve mine. 
For now, I am closing this question as solved.

```
m = data.frame()
for (k in 1:length(files)) {
  csv = read.csv(files[k], header = FALSE)
  data = csv[c(2:20, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350), c(1,2)]
  data[1,] <- mean(data[c(2:19),c(2)], na.rm=T)
  data <- data[-2:-19,]
  data[c(1),c(1)] = 200
  data$file = files[k]
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  m = rbind(m, data)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: @Sab already updated.

Comment: @AdamQuek I am only interested in the mean value of row 2 to 20 of the column in each file. Put together, the data frame shows mean and other rows for each file for all 1000 files. It's batch processing. That's why prefer an integration to my existing function. Makes sense? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files <- list.files(pattern='\\.csv')    
all <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=FALSE)
all.subset <- lapply(all, function(x)x[c(2:20, 50, 120, 150, 175, 200), c(1,2)])

col.means <- function(x) colMeans(x, na.rm=T)

do.call(rbind, lapply(all.subset, col.means))
```

Edit:

```
files <- list.files(pattern='\\.csv')
m <- data.frame()

for (k in files){
    csv <- read.csv(k, header = FALSE)[, c(1,2)]

    v1 <- mean(csv[2:20,1], na.rm=T)
    v2 <- mean(csv[2:20,2], na.rm=T)
    mean.val <- data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2, file=k)

    subset.data <- csv[c(50, 120, 150, 175, 200),]
    subset.data <- rbind(mean.val, subset.data)

    m <- rbind(m, subset.data)
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It's not showing up what I required. Also it's missing is the row#, and filename as a new column. Both are crucial identifiers.

Comment: What you are doing is, getting a mean for each csv file. I need mean as well as the other specified rows at row# 50, 100, 150 so on...not just mean of 2:20 rows. When getting mean, your code outputs a wrong row#. Are you not able to reproduce an input file to get the required output that's mentioned in my question? let me know please.

Comment: Please see my edit. I used part of your code and @MattJewett to customise my own code to fit the solution I needed. Let me know if you think my final code snippet can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
# Insert the mean of rows 2:20 into row 202
csv[202,"value"] <- mean(csv[2:20,"value])

# Drop rows 2:20 from the dataframe
csv <- csv[-2:-20,]
```